# Migrate website has cdn images

Tags: wordpress, migration, cdn

I have to migrate a website that no longer using its Media library but cloudfront, I wonder the process to migrate it will be any different?

Normally I use WP plugin Duplicator, All in one migration, or just copy files & database (change domain name) directly to the new server.
I wonder will it work the same for cdn content website or I have to do something else?

At the first day, I may use a temporary domain name and testing if it's ok we will redirect the live domain name to it.

Please give me advice if you have experienced this.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you use a plugin to integrate CloudFront?

Comment: I did not, I actually didn't know how they set it up. but Thanks !